# Counting variables to look for invariances/range conditions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, inverse-problems

A while back, I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028695/range-conditions-on-a-linear-operator) question on m.se.  I wasn't terribly happy with the answer, and when someone asked a very [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291824/consistency-range-conditions-for-integral-transform-mapping-into-higher-dimens) which isn't getting any action, it got me thinking again.  Let me rephrase the original question:

Suppose we have a linear operator $A:X(\Bbb{R}^n)\rightarrow X(\Bbb{R}^m)$ where $X$ is some appropriate function space structure like $L^2, C^\infty, \mathcal{S}$, and more importantly $m > n$.  For example, I'm thinking about the (extended) X-ray transform:

$$
Df(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x+ty)dt,\quad x,y\in \Bbb{R}^3
$$ This operator (defined on say $\mathcal{S}(\Bbb{R}^3)$), but it doesn't really matter) maps functions of 3 variables to functions of 6 variables. By "counting dimensions", we should have $6-3 = 3$ independent invariances or conditions which describe the range of $D$.  Indeed, such conditions are provided by [John's equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John%27s_equation).

My question is the following: suppose we have such an operator $A$ that increases dimension.  Must there exist conditions characterizing the range of $A$?

Perhaps a precise statement is as follows.  Let $K\in \mathcal{S}^\prime(\Bbb{R}^m\times\Bbb{R}^n)$, and define the operator $A:\mathcal{S}(\Bbb{R}^n)\rightarrow \mathcal{S}^\prime(\Bbb{R}^m)$ as

$$
A\varphi = \int_{\Bbb{R}^n}K(\cdot,y)\varphi(y)dy
$$  Must there exist $m-n$ nontrivial independent operators $R_j:\mathcal{S}^\prime(\Bbb{R}^m)\rightarrow\mathcal{S}^\prime(\Bbb{R}^m)$ such that $R_jA\varphi = 0$?